# Replace one string in a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of strings.

If one of the strings (e.g. at index 5) is the empty string, I want to replace it with "N".

How do I do that? The naive method (for a java programmer) does not work:

```
string_list[5] = "N"
```

gives

> 'str' object does not support item assignment

(string_list originally came from a .csv-file- that is why it might contain empty strings.)

Comment: Looks like `string_list` is actually a string, not a list of strings. Lists are mutable, so you should be able to replace its item just like you did.

Comment: You have simple string not list, and you can use replace method.

Comment: could you post an example of your `string_list` ?

Comment: I need to look at my code again and explain better. Give me a sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error seems to indicate that your string_list is not a list of string but a real string (that doesn't support assignement because a string is immutable).

If your string_list was a real list of strings, like this for example : `string_list = ["first", "second", "", "fourth"]`, then you will be able to do `string_list[2] = "third"` to obtain `string_list = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]`.

If you need to automatically detect where an empty string is located in your list, try with [index](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) :

```
string_list[string_list.index("")] = "replacement string"

print string_list
>>> ["first", "second", "replacement string", "fourth"]
```

Comment: I made a dumdum mistake: when splitting my original line I gave it an index so a string was returned, not a list. *Feeling embarrased*

Answer (score 2):

You say you have **a list of strings** but from you error it looks like you're trying to index a **string**

```
l =  ["a", "b", "", "c"]
```

Is a list of strings.

```
l = ["N" if not x else x for x in l]
```

Is a list of strings with empty strings replaced with "N"

Comment: Nice. Good something worthwhile came out of my mistake.

Comment: Anything for someone with a name like that. Made me laugh :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> s = 'abc de'
>>> s.replace(' ', 'N')
'abcNde'
```

As mentioned by the others, it sounds like `string_list` is actually a string itself, meaning that you can't use assignment to change a character.

Comment: @Aesthete Ha, no worries - I did too at first.

Answer (score 0):

In python work with lists and convert them to strings when need be.

```
>> str = list("Hellp")

>> str
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'p']

>> str[4] = 'o'

>> str
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

TO make it a string use

```
>> "".join(str)

'Hello World'
```

Python strings are immutable and they cannot be modified.

Or you could use [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Some thing like:

```
>> myStr = ['how', 'are', 'yew', '?']

>> myStr = [w.replace('yew', 'you') for w in myStr]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example iterates through lists of lists (sublists), in order to replace a string, a word:

```
myoldlist=[['aa bbbbb'],['dd myword'],['aa myword']]
mynewlist=[]
for i in xrange(0,3,1):
    mynewlist.append([x.replace('myword', 'new_word') for x in myoldlist[i]])

print mynewlist
# ['aa bbbbb'],['dd new_word'],['aa new_word']
```

Comment: Your two answers seem to be [almost identical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781828/replace-a-string-in-list-of-lists/36938886#36938886) you probably could consider refer one as your answer while the other you simply need to post a link in the comment (once your rep is >= 50)